# How to subscribe to Prism's Navigated event?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I tried with this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
     eventAggregator.GetEvent<ImportProgressReadyEvent().Subscribe(SubscriberMethod);   
}
```

and it works, but SubscriberMethod() of course gets called on construction before the page is navigated and visible. Is there a way to subscribe to some event handler (I assume it is the 'Navigated') which would get called once the navigation is done? So in my ViewModel I have something like this:

```
private void WhenNavigated()
        {
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<ImportProgressReadyEvent>().Subscribe(SubscriberMethod);
        }
```

Comment: There's a `Navigated` event on the [`Frame` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame_events(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can hook into that, but that requires you to have a `Frame` in your XAML.

Comment: What do you mean by _SubscriberMethod() of course gets called on construction_ ? The method in the `Subscribe` should only get called if a `Publish` happened on the `ImportProgressReadyEvent`

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I want something to determine when 'WhenNavigated()' is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to know about this event in your viewmodel, so I think that you're looking for the `INavigationAware` interface. It's got three methods:

```
public interface INavigationAware
{
    bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext);
    void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext);
    void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext);
}
```

The `OnNavigatedTo` will be fired once the view has been navigated to and the viewmodel with the interface has been imported/created. You can use the `NavigationContext` parameter to pass information between views, as well.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this too. the problem is that when I try to extend this interface, it says: 'does not implement interface member 'Prism.Regions.INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(Prism.Regions.NavigationContext)'

Comment: You'll need to implement all three methods. They don't have to do anything, and the `IsNavigationTarget` can just be hardcoded to return `true`.

Comment: Yes, it works, but again, 'OnNavigatedTo' gets called before the view appears, which is what I don't want :(